# react component not re rendering after change in usestate using context api

Tags: reactjs, react-context

the problem is when I am changing the state value of loading by deleting false and entering true or vice versa in the context js, my component is not re rendering , I have to refresh the page for the changed state value to show.
I am even console logging to see the changed value , but until I refresh the page I cannot see the change even in console.

this is my context.js , here i have set up the context api, and as you can see I am console logging the value of loading.

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { useCallback } from "react";

const url = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=";
const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  console.log(loading);
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{loading}}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};
export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

this is my index.js, I have properly wrapped my index js in context api

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { AppProvider}  from './context'
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppProvider>
    <App />
    </AppProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

this is my app js

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import { Navbar } from "./components/Navbar";
// pages
import { Home } from './pages/Home'
import { About } from './pages/About'
import { SingleCocktail } from './pages/SingleCocktail'
import { Error } from './pages/Error'
function App() {
 
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route  path="/about">
          <About />
        </Route>
        <Route  path="/cocktail/:id">
          <SingleCocktail />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="*">
          <Error />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think you should inject your `setLoading` method into the `AppContext`.

Comment: @DánielBoros I cannot do that it ill cause error

Comment: What is the error code?

Comment: " React Hook "useState" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function "